# Extract identical slices/indexed elements from all sublists

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested, slice

I'm trying to get `93, 96`, etc. I tried using slice without loop but it didn't work. I've tried it with:

```
a = [[[1, 0, 1], 93], [[1, 0, 1], 96]]
print(a[:][:][1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use comprehensions.

```
a = [[[1, 0, 1], 93], [[1, 0, 1], 96]]
print([i[1] for i in a])
```

Answer (score 4):

Jérôme's answer is probably more instructive and beneficial for a learner, but for conciseness' sake, this transposition should be suggested as well (using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
print(zip(*a)[1])
```